Multiple parameters in the URL path. It's possible? (DarkaOnLine)
Using Swagger to document a Laravel API, I got to the point of documenting a route with two path params. However, I can't pass both parameters in the Swagger url in any way, only the first one comes out.
Route:
Route::get('to_apply_or_unapply/{vacancy_id}/{action}', [Applications::class, 'toApplyOrUnapply'])->name('api.vacancies_user.to_apply_or_unapply');

Docs:
/**
 * @OA\Get(
 * path="/api/vacancies_user/to_apply_or_unapply/{vacancy_id}/{action}",
 * operationId="toApplyOrUnapply",
 * tags={"VacanciesUsers"},
 * summary="Apply or unapply to a vacancy",
 * description="Apply or unapply to a specific vacancy.",
 * security={{"bearerAuth": {}}},
 * @OA\Parameter(
 * name="vacancy_id",
 * in="path",
 * description="ID of the vacancy.",
 * required=true,
 * @OA\Schema(
 * type="integer"
 * )
 * ),
 * @OA\Parameter(
 * name="action",
 * in="path",
 * description="Action to perform (attach or detach).",
 * required=true,
 * @OA\Schema(
 * type="string",
 * enum={"attach", "detach"}
 * )
 * ),
 * @OA\Response(
 * response=200,
 * description="Success message confirming the action.",
 * @OA\JsonContent(
 * @OA\Property(
 * property="message",
 * type="string",
 * example="User John applied to Vacancy XYZ"
 * )
 * )
 * ),
 * @OA\Response(
 * response=404,
 * description="Invalid data or action provided.",
 * @OA\JsonContent(
 * @OA\Property(
 * property="error",
 * type="string",
 * example="Invalid data or action provided."
 * )
 * )
 * )
 * )
 */

But when executing the request, it comes out with:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/vacancies_user/to_apply_or_unapply/2/{action} (the "2" was the first parameter entered).
I appreciate any help
Sorry my bad english. I'm brazilian.
I tried passing the parameters in the url path, hoping the build would come out correctly. But unfortunately the second parameter was "{action}" without any filling.
